# Discord.py "member.move_to" function disconnecting users

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am creating a discord bot, that does 2 things:

1. When receiving a message from me "gamerjy" that says "MoveVoice1" it moves everyone into general VC.
2. When receiving "MoveVoice2" it moves everyone into they're roles VC, assigned in a JSON file.

With #2, its actually disconnecting me from any VC I'm in. The bot has all the perms, and is able to do it when I say "MoveVoice1". Please help.

I am expecting MoveVoice2 to move people into their specified VC's, but is disconnecting. MoveVoice1 works though.

```
import discord
import json
import time

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

guild_id = 1176809935091281991
gen_id = 1176809935552643085

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content != "MoveVoice1" and message.content != "MoveVoice2":
        return

    # Get the guild object
    guild = client.get_guild(guild_id) 

    # If Voice 1, Move everyone to General
    if message.content == "MoveVoice1":
        general_channel = guild.get_channel(gen_id)  # Replace GENERAL_CHANNEL_ID with the ID of the General voice channel
        for member in guild.members:
            await member.move_to(general_channel)
            print(f"Moved {member.name} to General voice channel")

    #If Voice 2, move everyone assigned on their roles of team
    if message.content == "MoveVoice2":
        with open("RoleToChannel.json", "r") as f:
            role_to_channel = json.load(f)

        for role, channel in role_to_channel.items():
            role_object = guild.get_role(int(role))

            for role_member in role_object.members:
                print(f"Attempting to move {role_member} to {channel}")
                try:
                    await role_member.move_to(guild.get_channel(channel))
                    print(f"Successfully moved {role_member} to {channel}")
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error moving {role_member}: {e}")







client.run('STACKOVERFLOW_PLACEHOLDER')  # Replace YOUR_BOT_TOKEN with your bot token
```

Comment: I think it is something in the json. You either have two or more roles that are in the .json file or none that are in it. If you have an exception that would be good to see. Also check what your print statement returns for `role_member` and `channel`

Comment: `role_member: gamerjy, channel: 1176810073562038332`

Thats the output for rolemember and channel

They are both objects

Comment: I think you should try to convert the channel property to an int. Other than that I see no possible issue.

Comment: It returns an error stating it takes in a `channel` object if I convert the object into an int (channel id). I belive I am creating that in my code.